# Customer registration: how to validate 'date of birth' of customer?

Tags: magento-2.1

Need to check whether user has 18 years old (that's simply to do in javascript) then display error/success message and pass further.

How to add validation for 'date of birth' field in customer registration form?

Which js I should extend for this purpose?

Comment: Check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241920/magento2-add-date-from-validation-for-dob-date-of-birth-field-in-customer-cre

Answer (score 0):

You should extend this file with your own validation rule.

> '/lib/web/mage/validation.js'

After  you added your own validation rule just add the following to your input field

```
 data-validate="{'Your-validation-name':true}"
```

example:

```
data-validate="{'custom-age-validation':true}"
```